# Change event is triggered twice instead of once

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, onchange

I am working on this html5 file uploader plugin but it has a bug which I can't understand and fix it.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/es8Vh/2/)

The idea of this plugin is to attach a group of function to a targeted button only when it is clicked.

But When I click on the **'button-1'** click event, the **'button-2'** click event has been triggered at the same time when the `on change event` is happening. I think the change event must have been triggered twice.

You can try to click on the upload button and see what I mean.

Any idea what goes wrong in this plugin?

```
(function($){

    // Attach this new method to jQuery
    $.fn.extend({ 

        // This is where you write your plugin's name
        upload_file_html5: function(options) {

            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                objectSuperparent:    '.media'
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $cm = this.click(function(e){

                // <a> button is the object in this case.
                var object = $(this);

                // Get other info from the element belong to this object group.
                var object_href = object.attr('href');
                var object_parent = object.parent();
                alert($cm.selector);

                // Trigger the click event on the element.
                // Due to security policies triggering click on the input type=file is not allowed/supported in some browsers and Opera is one of them.
                //$('input[type=file]').trigger('click'); // or:
                $(".upload-file",object_parent).click();

                return false;

            });

            // Trigger ajax post when ever the file is changed by the user.
            var $cm_2 = $(".upload-file").change(function(){

                // <input> is the object in this case.
                var object = $(this);

                var object_form = object.parent();
                var object_superparent = object.parents(o.objectSuperparent);
                var path_config = $($cm.selector,object_superparent).attr('href');
                var path_post = object_form.attr('action');

                alert($cm.selector);
                //alert(path_config);

                ....
                ....

            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my variant of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/es8Vh/3/
Basic jQuery plugin structure:

```
$.fn.pluginName = function() {
    return this.each(function() { // <-- this is important
        // code here
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer, dfsq. But how can get/ return the name (which is `.button-1`) of the clicked button by using alert - `alert($cm.selector);`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/es8Vh/5/ `this` is your current DOM object, $(this) correponding jQuery object.

Comment: But you'd better off not to rely on selector because it can be anything. E.g.: `#button1`, `.button1`, `#some > .button:first`, etc

Comment: got it. thanks dfsq. jsfiddle.net/es8Vh/5 alert each button but I only want to alert the button which is clicked - is it possible?